# FastAPI: how to return JSONResponse and StreamingResponse

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Is it possible to return both a json and a zip file at the same time with FastAPI ?
This is the tentative endpoint but it doesn't work:

```py
@app.post("/search")
async def structure_search()
    json_response = {"item1": result1, "item2": result2}

    zip_io = BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_io, mode="w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as temp_zip:
        for fpath in glob.glob("directory/*"):
            temp_zip.write(fpath)

    return JSONResponse(content=json_response), 
           StreamingResponse(iter([zip_io.getvalue()]),
                             media_type="application/x-zip-compressed", 
                             headers={"Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename=results.zip"},
                             )
```

Comment: What do you expect your browser to do with that? Download a zip file or use the JSON for something useful? Generally you'll have to base64 encode content and include it a JSON field if you want to combine the response into a single response format.

Comment: Yes that is a question I asked myself after posting, actually I decided to do something else, I generate only a zip file with the json as a txt file inside if necessary, otherwise I return only the JSONResponse.